# jQuery DataTables Horizontal Scroll and Filtering Not Working Together

Tags: datatables

I am using Datatables and require both horizontal scrolling and filtering. It appears that they try to write to the same area and I can't get both to work. If I enable filtering, it will filter once then then filter disappears.

Any clues? It is within an intranet so I can't post code.

Comment: -1 for no code example, no research effort shown. Check DataTables forums and existing DataTables GitHub issues. If your case is not there, create a test case and publish it in the DataTables forums at https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/12899/post-test-cases-when-asking-for-help-please-read

Comment: you can put your test case (run-able example of your problem) on a public site like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) or **[live.DataTables.net](http://live.datatables.net/)** or anywhere else.. supportive?

Comment: Fair enough. I rescind my previous comment and will look to generalize the issue.

Comment: Fair enough. My -1 vote was because you did not keep basic Stack Overflow rules (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The link to DataTables forums and test case is a MUST if you want Allan Jardine (the author) to help you. I needed his help myself just 2 days ago and I also had to provide a test case. If you improve your question I'll remove my downvote

Comment: I have found the answer by creating a separate area for filtering that is outside of the datatable. In the future, I will be better about the following the rules and providing test cases. Here is a link to what I am implementing: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html Note that it resides outside of the datatable

Comment: DataTables site is best source of further questions you may have on that topic. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
After many attempts I found two solutions to solve this.
Here are the options:

1) If you want to put the column filters after the first header (title of column and ordering), the following code snippet worked:

```
table.columns().eq(0).each( function ( colIdx ) {
    $( 'input', otable.column( colIdx ).header() ).on( 'keyup change', function() {
        table
            .column( colIdx )
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    });
});
```

2) Else, type the following code snippet after create a table object:

```
table.columns().eq(0).each( function ( colIdx ) {
     $( 'input', 'th:nth-child('+(colIdx+1)+')' ).on( 'keyup change', function() {
          table
              .column( colIdx )
              .search( this.value )
              .draw();
     });
});
```

Regards.
Joao Lucas.

Comment: Where do you put the first code? directly on the DataTable script?